# Construct a global invariant measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, manifolds, dynamical-systems

Given a (Hamiltonian) flow $\phi^t:\mathbb{R} \times D \rightarrow D$ on some compact set $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ ($D$ can be seen as some level set of the Hamiltonian), and let $\{U_\alpha\}$ be a finite cover of $D$.

Suppose on each $U_\alpha$, there exists a measure $\mu_\alpha$ which is invariant under the flow, i.e.  given $A\subset U_\alpha$ and $T$ that are small enough, we have $ |t|\leq T,\; \phi^t(A) \subset U_\alpha$ and 
$$\quad  \mu_\alpha(A) = \mu_\alpha(\phi^t(A)).$$

Is there a way to define a global invariant measure on $D$? If not, what additional information I will need to do this?

Comment: The assumption $\phi^t(A) \subset U_\alpha$ (even for small $t$) is too restrictive. Do you perhaps want to make some other assumptions?

Comment: Could you explain more? I thought if we had more conditions on the flow, the invariant measure in some sense would be easier to exist.

Comment: Try with a rotation and you'll see the problems. Perhaps you should tells us the context.